# Do angular library dependecies are visible to parent project?

Tags: angular

I created an Angular library and installed there @ng-select. Library builds fine.
However, when I use this library in my project I am getting an error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '@ng-select/ng-select' or its corresponding type declarations.

6 import * as i5 from "@ng-select/ng-select";
```

Does it mean I have to install @ng-select also in my project?
Is there any chance to export it from my library?

Comment: You're not showing very much, but you have to specify `peerDependencies` in your library `package.json`. Then when you want to install your package you have to use `npm i @my/library` instead of `npm install --save @my/library`. This will install the peerDependencies too ([example](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/package.json#L24))